# Jmeter req/s rate degradation, Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jmeter

I`m doing a load test with Jmeter 3.0. The graph Response Codes per Second shows me a sawtooth picture like this (50 threads):

[image]
Tryed to monitor java with VisualVM and a graph of loaded classes and gc are correlating with previous:
[image]
[image]

So it seems like rps grows up only after Full GC and the drops down.

I restarted Jmeter with key -verbose:class > classes.txt to have a look what kind of classes are loading. This file was mostly full with thousands of entities like these:

```
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128239 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128259 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128262 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128261 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128263 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128265 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128266 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128269 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128271 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128270 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128257 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128260 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128273 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128267 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128268 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128280 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128275 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128277 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
[Loaded org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__128272 from file:/C:/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar]
```

Only one thing which is helping to hold an uniform load is to decrease heap size or increase a number of threads (to force more often gc). Tried different java settings and the last one was:

```
java -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:class > classes.txt -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Comment: nice analysis! what is your JMeter script driving this traffic? Something gets dropped and recreated quite a bit.

Comment: JS calls suggest some JS code inside the script. Do you have any pre/post processors, If controllers, etc that may use JS?

Comment: @KirilS. yes i do. a lot of If controllers and pre/post beanshell postprocessors

Answer (score 0):

Your answer already has the reason and the solution, just to summarise.

- Increase [JVM Heap](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) to 70-80% of your total available RAM
- Use [Concurrent Mark Sweep Garbage Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html)
- In your case consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of JavaScript

References:
 1. [Apache JMeter Best Practices](http://Best%20Practices)
 2. [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: I use concurrent mark sweep gc. About JSR223 i created another question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219321/jmeter-3-0-jsr223groovy-vs-beanshell

Comment: Its not the GC settings or the memory available. Its your third point, the script does not follow best practice. v0devil, you need to change your script to drive load only, and to use only regex to pull values at most.